# make a path that increments the count

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, increment

I'm trying to make a post request that will increment my schema using express and mongoose,
which is :

```
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  formName: String,
  inputs: [
    {
      inputLabel: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },

      inputType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['text', 'color', 'date', 'email', 'tel', 'number']
      },

      inputValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ],
  numOfSubs: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

for my code purposes I want to make a route that will increase by 1 the numOfSubs everytime I use it,since there are a few listings, I have the ID so I need to search it, and I'm not sure how to write the path

```
router.post('/increase', (req, res) => {
 "find and increase by 1 " 

});
```

and I will use the fetch like so:

```
fetch('/api/items/increase', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ _id }),//the ID I of the collection I want to increment
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you use mongoose?

Comment: @MohammedEssehemy yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this using mongo [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator

```
router.post('/increase', (req, res, next) => {
const _id = req.body._id;

   MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(_id , { $inc: {numOfSubs: 1} }, { new: true },  (err,updateRes)=>{
      if(err) return next(err);
      return res.json({sucess: true});
   });

});
```

Comment: its suppose to have two returns?

Comment: could you just explain to me what new:true means?

Comment: This means return the new document after update, i.e with the incremented count.
I put it in case you need it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand quite yet, where is this document returning?

Comment: the callback function receives second parameter which I named `updateRes`, if you don't pass this option you will get the initial document before incrementing the count, in this case I passed `{new: true}` to return the new document after increment.